# SQL Grouped Filter by Subquery

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

I have following Tables:

```
---------VBUK-----------  
ID      WBSTK   
77807   C  
77808   C  
80345   A  
80383   A  
80989   A  
85997   C  
91212   A  
91397   A  

----GRPID------  
GROUP | ID  
0001 | 77807  
0001 | 77808  
0001 | 80345  
0002 | 80383  
0002 | 80989  
0002 | 85997  
0001 | 91212  
0001 | 91397
```

So I want to get as a result all "A"s which have a smaller ID than any "C".
Only for VBUK it would work with this code:

```
select  t1.ID, t1.WBSTK  
from VBUK t1  
inner join VBUK t2 on t2.ID > t1.ID and t2.WBSTK='C'   
where t1.WBSTK='A'
```

But now I want to have this comparison on group level.
So for this example my output should be:

```
GROUP  |  ID   |  WBSTK   
0002   | 80383 |  A  
0002   | 80989 |  A
```

Nothing for GROUP 0001 because there is no A bigger than the MAX C for this group.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for window functions:

```
select gv.*
from (select g.*, v.WBSTK,
             min(case when v.WBSTK = 'C' then vbuk.id end) over (partition by g.group) as min_c_id
      from groups g join
           vbuk v
           on g.id = v.id
     ) gv
where gv.WBSTK = 'A' and gv.id < min_c_id;
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure but shouldn't it be MAX(case when...) in line 3?

Comment: @David . . . No.  The question is:  "So I want to get as a result all "A"s which have a smaller ID than any "C"."  Hence you need the smallest id for C.

Comment: you are completely right!
Logical error on my side! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if get your point, but for me it seems you only need to add the group info:

```
select  t1.ID, t1.WBSTK  , t3.group
from VBUK t1  
inner join VBUK t2 on t2.ID > t1.ID and t2.WBSTK='C'   
left join GRPID t3 on t3.id = t1.id
where t1.WBSTK='A'
```